# Why instance of class WebBaseNetscapePluginView not respond selector in safari4?

Tags: cocoa, safari, simbl

I am developing a plug-in with Safari. I followed the adblocker sourcecode to swizzle the method:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:pluginPackage:URL:baseURL:MIMEType:attributeKeys:attributeValues:loadManually:DOMElement:
```

of class WebBaseNetscapePluginView but I found that didn't respond in Safari4. Why?

Comment: We need a little more detail. What do mean Safari did not respond? Does the plug-in not load or do you see some other unexpected behavior.

Comment: The title says “WebBaseNetscapePluginView not respond selector”, so I think he means he tried to exchange implementations, but there was no implementation already there to exchange with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They either removed that method, changed its selector, or moved it to another class. They might have changed how the method works, or added functionality, and changed the selector accordingly.

You should ask a new question with what you intend to do by swizzling this method, asking how you should do it. Swizzling this method clearly isn't it.

Comment: ok I have resolved this problem: and in safari4 , this method is worked: -(id)initWithFrame:pluginPackage:URL:baseURL:MIMEType:attributeKeys:attributeValues:loadManually:element: